# Jagged edges on pseudo element border

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a visual effect using CSS, which you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/FL8Ug/

The problem at this point, is that when I use both `border-top` and `border-bottom` on the :after pseudo element, the edges become "jagged" (in Chrome).

**When you remove the border-bottom for example, the top triangle (which is the top half of the right border) becomes much smoother.**

I tried applying both `-webkit-transform:translateZ(0)` and `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden`, which has fixed strange behaviour like this for me in the past, but to no result.

Does anyone know if there's a fix for this?

(I also noticed that in Firefox, the border is always jagged, also after removing the border-bottom.)

Note: I'd rather not use both the :before and :after pseudo elements, because I'm already using the :before for another effect.

Comment: In FF this can be fixed by changing border-top to: `border-top: 30px solid blue;`, but you need to change it to `31px` in Chrome, so this is an imperfect solution.

Comment: I think you're referring to the pixel difference in height in Firefox. That's not the issue I'm referring to :) (but to the edges not being smooth)

Comment: The changes I suggested fix the jagged edges. The imperfection comes with the fact that you need two different values for two different browsers.

Comment: If I change `border-top: 29px solid blue;` to: `border-top: 30px solid blue;` I still have jagged edges.. Do you have an updated Fiddle?

Comment: Oh, if you're talking about the sides rather than the bottom, that can't be fixed. You can use SVG to get smooth lines instead.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. I'll try using SVG. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I appear to have fixed this. For some reason it's only when you use three borders that it gets jagged but if you just use two it stays smooth. So I split your after in two and made a before for the third border.

[Codepen of the solution](http://codepen.io/SaltedLiquorice/pen/oIwpd)`enter code here`